# Best way to programmatically link to multiple categories (union/intersection)

Tags: categories, permalinks, taxonomy, multi-taxonomy-query

This question assumes that you know about the various complex taxonomy queries available from the WP_Query API. I know about `tax_query` as well as about things like `category__and`, which allow you to run multi-term queries inside a template.

It also takes for granted the knowledge that you can manually create links, both pretty (`/category/mac+mobile/`) and ugly (`/?cat=2+3`) that will generate the results similar to many of the `tax_query` (or at least `category__and`) options.

The question is: What is the best way to generate such links within code, so that a theme can automatically link to screens showing complex mixes of categories.

- The solution should be forward compatible and use standard WP if possible.
- It should ideally work with any possible permalinks and category-permalink configuration.
- Ideally it would work with any order of categories, as well as with categories nested inside a hierarchical taxonomy.
- It should accomodate both intersections (a+b only posts in both categories are returned) and unions (a,b any post in one or the other category works).

As far as I can tell there is no built-in function that can achieve this. The similar function is `get_term_link()` but it only accepts a single term. Ideally core would have something like `get_tax_query_link()` that accepted a tax_query and rendered a link that would show the desired results.

Comment: _Ideally core would have..._ - this sounds like a trac ticket, not a question. :) What kind of answer are you looking for here precisely?